# Opening Ledger with wallet v0.14.1.0 Boron Butterfly

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I have a Monero GUI wallet v0.14.0.0 Boron Butterfly whick I open with my Ledger Nano S.

I downloaded Monero GUI v0.14.1.0 Boron Butterfly for Windows 64-bit.

When opening, it says:
"wallet can't be opened: unsupported device application version: 1.2.2  At least 1.3.1 is required."

Can you help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to upgrade your Ledger Monero app to v1.3.1. Thereafter, you should be able to properly use your wallet.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Its working now.  Still learning every day ...

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer satisfactory answered your question, please mark it as such by the way.